# Potion of Transmutation: Wight/Acolyte possible?

Tags: werewolv.es

Is it possible, when using a Potion of Transmutation on Coven/Undead, to reroll into Acolyte/Wight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Puppetmaster, VoodooDoctor and Revenant are all impossible however, because these are strictly "one of" roles in the game, otherwise the puppet/zombie/corpse control could get... interesting.